# Combining regular expressions to split a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string "Welcome Jacob (jacob@test.com).
I need the output as "Welcome J"
i.e I need my output as the First word of a string and the First letter of the second word of the string.
I can do that by
`string entireString = "Welcome Jacob (jacob@test.com)";
string [] words = a.Split(' ');
string 2ndLetter = words[1].Substring(0,1);
Console.WriteLine(words[0]+" "+2ndLetter);`

Is there a better way to do it?
Something like combining regular expression for space and for the first letter of a word?
Something like

```
var name = Regex.Split(temp, @"/^((\s)|([a-zA-Z ])')$"
```

Comment: *Is there a better way to do it?* - What do you find not good in current way?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you'd consider this better, but you could do it in one line.

```
string output = entireString.Substring(0, entireString.IndexOf(" ") + 2)
```

Comment: This specifically gives you everything in a string up to and including the first space and one character past it.  If there is no space it attempts to give you just the first character.  It will throw an exception if the first space is the last character of the string, or for an empty string.

Comment: Also this could use the overload of `IndexOf` that takes a `char`. `IndexOf(' ')` instead.

Comment: @juharr True enough, but the original poster did say there would be two words in their string, so in this scenario, that should never be a problem. But, if there is a possibility of the scenarios you mentioned, you could always check to make sure the string isn't empty or that space isn't the last character first, or use try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do something like this, there is no need to actually split the string:

```
string entireString = "Welcome Jacob (jacob@test.com)";
var r = new Regex(@"^\S+\s\S");
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(entireString).Value);   // outputs Welcome J
```

The regex matches 1 or more non-space characters, a space, and then a single non-space character. You can make it more strict if necessary.